# OSX: localhost php file works but not other files?

Tags: image, webserver, osx-mountain-lion

I have a php file named 'db.php' in my folder /Library/WebServer/Documents/ and I can reach it but I have a picture '1.png' in the same folder but I cannot reach it.

**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access /1.png on this server.

How come?

Comment: give the read mode for group and other to 1.png,
browse to the path using cd, then type chmod go+r 1.png

Comment: I want to allow all files in the Sites folder. How would I do that?

Comment: I Tried using chmod go+r /Users/myusername/Sites/ and that might've worked.